# Why is Eclipse unable to see groovy.sql.Sql?

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy

Specs: OS Linux Mint 18.3, Groovy 2.5.8, Eclipse 2019-06, Java 11.

I want to make a simple connection to a MySQL dbase from a Groovy script.

So far the script looks like this:

```
import java.sql.*
import groovy.sql.Sql

println  "hello world"
```

This runs fine at the CLI (with the usual "reflection" warnings of course).

Whatever I do in Eclipse I'm getting a horrid white-cross-in-red-box (bane of my life) which says "Groovy: unable to resolve class groovy.sql.Sql".

I've looked at the project's settings for Java and Groovy. I've tried removing and then adding back the JRE (Java 11) for the project. I've tried cleaning the project. I've tried restarting Eclipse.

In other words, I've tried doing most of the things (ways of fighting back) that I've learnt from many years of bitter struggle against my mortal enemy Eclipse.

Googling the error has produced only people who misspelt things.

By the way, when you look at things in the "Problems" panel, the error is described as a "Java Problem".

I'm feeling I must be doing something immensely stupid and that the answer is easy. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: You may need to add groovy libraries to the build path..?

Comment: Thanks... they're there.

Answer (score 2):

Groovy 2.5 does not have the same "fat jar" packaging as earlier Groovy versions did. You need to add groovy-sql to your project or to your ~/.groovy/lib directory. And you may need to add "requires org.codehaus.groovy.sql;" to your module-info (if your project is modular).

Comment: Thanks.  I'm a bit confused.  Even without getting hold of this .jar file (I also had to create the directory ~/.groovy/lib) I *am* able to run the file without problems at the CLI.  Conversely, in **Eclipse**, if I create ~/.groovy/lib and download the right version of the .jar file from Maven Central I *still* find that although the nasty error mark has gone, I still can't get the thing to run (as a Groovy script): I get "(line) 4: unable to resolve class groovy.sql.Sql"

Comment: Groovy CLI uses groovy-starter.conf to load up several jars from the distribution. Eclipse does not deploy the full Groovy distribution.

Comment: Once you add any jars to ~/.groovy/lib you need to refresh your Groovy Libraries classpath container for it to make the jars available to your project.

Comment: Thanks... I did do a refresh ... and then I started up Eclipse again: that didn't work. I'm not on the machine right now. Do I have to go into Windows --> Prefs to refresh this container? Is it obvious what I have to do?

Comment: @mikerodent I was running into the same issue, if you are using gradle you can add `compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-sql:$groovyVersion"` to your dependencies block and that should help your IDE / gradle runner! I'm not an eclipse user but probably you need to somehow point it at your groovy SDK and refresh that somehow